# How to write rotated bitmap into specific file without compress android

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation, sd-card, fileoutputstream

I want to rotate and save rotated bitmap to specific file path without compress it. Before i have used the below code for rotate, compress and store it to a specific file. Now i dnt want to compress my bitmap. Please suggest me an idea to rotate and save the bitmap into specified path.

```
  public static void compressToStandard(String file) {

    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmOptions);

    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = getInSampleSize(bmOptions);

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, bmOptions);
        bitmap = ExifUtils.rotateBitmap(file, bitmap);
        Log.i("ImageUtils", "compressed bitmap size:" + bitmap.getWidth() + "x" + bitmap.getHeight());
       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, new FileOutputStream(file));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

when i call this method. I will pass my image path to this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNG is lossless so you can use `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG`

**Compresion**

```
    Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for 
    small size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. Some
    formats, like PNG which is lossless, will ignore the
    quality setting
```

Comment: @Sangeetha still have issue?

Comment: `Now i dnt want to compress my bitmap.` But you do.  `and save the bitmap into specified path.`. You are not saving the bitmap. You save a png.